# unavailable project - The type or namespace name could not be found on multiple solution

Tags: c#

I'm having some errors on multiple projects under my solution.

```
CS0246  C# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The projects are labeled as (unavailable)
This is labeled as incompatible before though not so sure why its changed status but same errors. Tried to Clean/build and rebuild the solution but the error still the same.

Also I tried the target framework but not so sure on how to do that thing.
Another solution I tried is the add reference but can't figure out what reference to add.

Im not so sure if I'm missing some updates or what so. Tried to install fix/azure and the visual studio 2015 updates.

output error:

```
Line 67:        {
Line 68:            if (_traceWriter == null) InitWriter();
Line 69:            lock (_traceWriter)
Line 70:            {
Line 71:                // If the date has changed, close the current stream and create a new file for today's date
```

error list.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name '***' does not exist in the namespace '***' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

other error description

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name '***' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name '***' does not exist in the current context
```

output from general upon load of solution w/ building the solution

```
Deserializing the project state for project 'database.sqlproj'...
Detecting file changes for project 'database.sqlproj'...
Deserialization has been completed for project 'database.sqlproj'.
```

UpgradeLog [here](http://prntscr.com/ap5ken) have some error on the .wixproj though I install the latest wix driver not sure if I need to setup anything else other than that.

Comment: If a project is "unavailable" then I'm pretty sure the reason goes into the "Output" window or similar. Can you check in there for errors?

Comment: see the output error in the post. see if that help. the error goes to the framework folder.

Comment: Sorry - I mean that when you first open your solution, you should check the "Output" window (`View -> Output`) for more detailed information of why the project is unavailable.

Comment: check the updated post

Comment: Please can you check the OUTPUT window (View -> Output) immediately after opening your solution. This will tell you why your projects are unavailable and thus let you fix your issue.

Comment: do i have to build first? the solution is on cloud. nothing much displays upon on load. see the output above

Comment: No, don't build it. Open the solution in visual studio, then check the output window. That's it!

Comment: Check the latest edit. I added the output upon load of solution nothing much displayed. also the upgradelog I have 4 logs though that sums up all.